# Express a function with power-of-k in a polynomial form

Tags: polynomials

I want to express a function $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)^{k}$, where $n$ is an arbitrary positive integer and $k$ is an arbitrary positive real number. Is it any way to find out how to express the coefficient of $x_i$? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the so-called multinomial formula, which is an easy generalization of the formula for $(a+b)^n$.

I could copy here the formula, but it is better if you read the [appropriate wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

In this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654233/number-of-terms-in-the-expansion-of-left1-frac1x-frac1x2-rightn/1654263#1654263) I explained how to get the case $(a+b+c)^n$.